# Summation combined with limits

Tags: limits, summation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n} ((r+1)\sin(π/r+1)-r\sin(π/r)$$

What I have tried so far I have posted in the image can you please tell me what to do from there on
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6exCz.jpg

Answer (score 3):

After collapsing the telescoping sum, you have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1) \sin \frac{\pi}{n+1}= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \pi \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1}}{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}= \pi,$$

since

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x }{x} = 1$$

Comment: I cannot believe that this hadn't yet received an up vote.  It is both clear ad concise.  +1 -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks I appreciate it.  And I must say having crossed paths a few times you are one of the most civil high rep users on this site.

Comment: Thank you!  That made my night.